# Two threads handle connection and read events independently

Tags: java, multithreading, nio

I am using NIO. At the beginning, I used one thread to handle all connections and read events.
The code is roughly as follows:

```
    private void mainLoop() {
        while (selector.isOpen()) {
            selector.select();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                keys.remove();
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    accept(key);
                } else if (key.isReadable()) {
                    read(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void accept(SelectionKey key) {
        ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
        SocketChannel socketChannel = ssc.accept();
        socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
        socketChannel.register(selector, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
    }

    private void read(SelectionKey key) {
        // read data and process
    }
```

Everything worked fine, and I tested it using `JMeter` with a throughput of about 6300/sec.

Then I tried to use 2 threads, each with a selector (my computer has 6 cores), one thread is responsible for receiving connection events, and then registering it to the other selector. The code is roughly as follows:

```
    private void mainLoop1() {
        while (selector1.isOpen()) {
            selector1.select();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector1.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                keys.remove();
                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    ServerSocketChannel ssc = (ServerSocketChannel) key.channel();
                    SocketChannel socketChannel = ssc.accept();
                    socketChannel.configureBlocking(false);
                    // wakeup thread2 to handle read event
                    selector2.wakeup();
                    socketChannel.register(selector2, SelectionKey.OP_READ);
                } 
            }

        }

    }

    private void mainLoop2() {
        while (selector2.isOpen()) {
            selector2.select();
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector2.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                keys.remove();
                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    read(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This approach is problematic:
`thread1` wakeup `thread2`, `thread2` checks that there are no events and blocks again, and `thread1` try to `register`, blocked. (Seems like `selector#select` and `selector#register` is synchronized)

What is the best way to solve this problem? I tried this:

```
    private void mainLoop2() {
        while (selector2.isOpen()) {
            // no block
            int selectNow = selector2.selectNow();
            if (selectNow == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            Iterator<SelectionKey> keys = selector2.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (keys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = keys.next();
                keys.remove();
                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (key.isReadable()) {
                    read(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Throughput can reach 7000 with this approach. Is this a good solution? This way `mainloop2`will always execute without blocking.  I also tried to make the selector select 10 milliseconds at a time: `selector.select(10)`, But then the throughput goes back to around 6300, which is the same as using a single thread.

Besides, `Netty` seems to use different threads to handle events. Can anyone tell me how `Netty` handles this problem?(Or there is no such problem at all
). I am not very familiar with the source code of netty.

Comment: A typical way of doing this is to have some kind of acceptor thread that accepts connections and a pool of event threads that take care of the regular read/write events. Once a connection is accepted, it is handed over to one of the event threads. This way you can scale the read/write events by increasing the size of the pool. I'm not sure of selectNow or select with timeout is the way to go; it will lead to spinning and can consume a lot of resources.

Comment: In your 1st listing, the costliest operation is `read`, I think. And it is something that can be done concurrently **(a)** while waiting for other connections **and** **(b)** while other `read`s are happening. In this listing, it seems to be happening synchronously. Considering (a) and (b), did you try submitting `read()` as a task to an `ExecutorService` so that it happens concurrently? I shall be interested in knowing what resulted.

Comment: @SreeKumar  Sorry for delay, I tried to use the thread pool at the beginning, but the throughput was not as good as that of a thread (Around 5000). The reason should be: 1. The operation after reading the data is pure cpu, and the execution will end soon 2. Using the thread pool, I need to use some thread-safe data structures to ensure thread safety.

Comment: You don't need to wakeup the 2nd selector to 'handle the read event'. There isn't one yet.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the source code of tomcat (v9.0.31). Simply put, he will have an `acceptor` and a `poller`(like my `thread2`). If the acceptor receives a connection event, he will add an event to a queue and wakeup poller. The poller will check whether there are new events, and if so, register `OP_READ` and process the Read operation. Please point out if I am wrong.
[image]